# MIPS LUI and SW LB Operations

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

so I'm trying to solve this problem it reads as follows,
Taking to account that the address of $t0 is 0x10000000

```
lui $t0,0x6F90
sw $t0,4($t0)
lb $t0,6($t0)
```

What's the value of $t0 in a little endian format?
So I after the first operation we get $t0=6F90000, after that I store $t0 in position 4 which is basically duplicating $t0, so $t0=6F900006F90000.
After that I go to position 6 and extract the byte, in this case 90 and extend its signal so the answer should be 0xFFFFFF90, but my colleague told me its wrong and wouldn't explain it to me.
Can anyone please tell me what im doing wrong

Comment: The store stores a word into memory at locations 0x6F900004-0x6F90007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You went wrong at `$t0=6F900006F90000`. That obviously can't happen as `$t0` is a 32 bit register.  `sw $t0,4($t0)` actually writes `$t0` **into memory** at address `4+$t0`. So that means the memory will look like:

```
address   value
6F900004:  00
6F900005:  00
6F900006:  90
6F900007:  6F
```

The `lb $t0,6($t0)` then loads a signed byte from address `6+$t0 = 6F900006`. That contains `90` which is `FFFFFF90` when sign extended to 32 bits. This is your final value in `$t0`.

Comment: Thank you! So my final value is right?! I thought it was wrong dang

Comment: @HelpMeBro: This assumes a little-endian MIPS machine.  MIPS can run in big or little-endian mode.  MARS simulates a little-endian MIPS, so this applies there.  (Big-endian MIPS would store the bytes of the word in memory as 6F, 90, 00, 00, so the load result would be 0)

Comment: @PeterCordes true, but I intentionally deleted that part because the question said: _"What's the value of $t0 in a **little endian format**?"_

Answer (score 0):

You have some incorrect ideas.  The store stores a word into memory at locations 0x6F900004-0x6F900007.

```
lui $t0, 0x6F90      # sets $t0 to 0x6F900000
sw  $t0, 4($t0)      # stores to memory at addresses 0x6F900004-0x6F900007; does not change $t0
lb  $t0, 6($t0)      # $t0=FFFFFF90
```